# How to create a common mapping template for indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

For the app i created, the indices are generated once in a week. And the type and nature of the data is not varying and that implies, I need the same mapping type for these indices. Is it possible in elasticsearch to apply the same mapping to all the indices as they are created?. This could avoid me the overhead of defining mapping each time the index is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can employ index template to address your problem. The official documentation can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).
A use case of how to apply the same with examples can be found in this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/dynamic-index-creation-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you can use what is called an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html). Since your mapping type is stable, that's the perfect condition for using index templates.

It's as easy as creating an index. See below, whenever you want to index a document in an index whose name matches `my_*`, ES will select that template and create the index for you using the given mappings, settings and aliases:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '{
    "template" : "my_*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "my_alias" : {}
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            "properties" : { 
                "my_field": { "type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

It's basically the technique used by Logstash when it needs to index new logs for each new day in a new daily index.